# Check Before Inserting

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check a value before inserting. However for some reason I can't figure it out. Here's my code:

```
set @accID = (select id from table2); 

IF @accID IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO task
    (account_id)
    VALUES (@accID);
END IF;
```

What is wrong with the code above as it shows invalid sql syntax error?

Comment: you can't use `IF` like that outside of a stored procedure.

Comment: Nobody ever needs to check a value before inserting

Comment: Can you not just restrict `account_id` to being `NOT NULL`? This would eliminate the need for this logic by just placing an `IGNORE` in your `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be all you need.

IF(@accID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO task
    (account_id)
    VALUES (@accID)
END

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same effect with a slightly strange `INSERT SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO task (account_id)
SELECT @accID
FROM DUAL
WHERE @accID IS NOT NULL
;
```

[DUAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) is a fake table built into MySQL; and is needed because you can't have a `WHERE` without a `FROM`.

If using an RDBMS that does not have a construct similar to DUAL, it is likely it can be replaced with a simple subquery `(SELECT 1) AS dummyTbl`